# How to export many small clips in a sequence out as separate video files in Adobe Premier?

Tags: premiere, video-editor, adobe, adobe-media-encoder

I have a video that I've chopped up into many small segments within the main sequence:
[image: many small segments in sequence]
You might notice that I took one main video and then used markers to select exact frames and then used the razor tool to slice it up and then deleted the parts I do not want to export

Instead of putting all of these segments together into a single video, I need to export each clip or segment (sorry not sure of the actual term of these clips in Premier) as a separate video file.

Is this possible with Adobe Premier and if so, how might I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to create sequences for each of your clips and batch export those sequences.